# determine connections limit enforced by my ISP

Tags: tcp, udp, isp

I know my new ISP is enforcing a lot of different limitations.
They refuse to say what are the limits.

To determine bandwidth I can use sites like http://www.voiptest.org/
(BTW it shows me ~15% of what I am promised to have (sic!))

I noticed that there is probably also a limit on number of opened connections.
To determine it, I picked a random torrent with more than 10 000 seeders. 
I am able to connect up to 50.
Torrent trick is easy, but it is not a perfect solution, because torrent connections are probably classified to some P2P pool with different limits.

**The question is:** what are another ways to determine maximum number of opened connections silently enforced by my ISP?

I Ask for ideas. I am a programmer and I use Linux. I can write some shell script, python or c code, or whatever. It's not a problem, but who to connect to not look like some DOS attacker. 
Do you know some host pools I can open a lot (>100?) of connections to?
Any other ideas?

Thank you

Comment: And yet torrent is not a good example, as most bittorrent clients enforce a limit of 50 peers per torrent by default (adjustable).

Comment: This page from EFF has a table of "ISP Testing software". Mainly this deals with forged RSTs, etc, but may be helpful: https://www.eff.org/testyourisp

Comment: @MartinoDino: I am aware of my torrent client connection limits. I set it to 200 and still get only 50. Thanks anyway for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`M-Lab` aka [measurementlab](http://measurementlab.net/measurement-lab-tools) was created for that purpose, you can use their tools to check if your provider enforces limits and what they are.

Answer (score 1):

If your ISP cannot or will not disclose limits, how do they expect you to comply?  You might consider changing ISPs.